# Can you give priority to a single topic when KafkaListener listens to multiple topics?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, listener, spring-kafka

Anyone knows how to give a priority to a single kafka topic when my @KafkaListener listens to multiple topic?

Below my code example:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "priority", topics = { "${prio-topic}" }, concurrency = "1", autoStartup = "true")
    @KafkaListener(id = "nonPriority", topics = { "${not-prio-topic-1}",
            "${not-prio-topic-2}", "${not-prio-topic-3}",
            "${not-prio-topic-4}", concurrency = "1", autoStartup = "true")
    public synchronized void  listenManyEntryTopic(String message) {}
```

My problem is that i want to read from the topic `prio-topic` before the others nonPrio topics. And only if my `prio-topic` is empty I should start consuming the other topics without any specific order.
Any hint/suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

There is no functionality in kafka to differentiate between priority vs non-priority topic messages. To solve your problem, one of the solution is to split the priority processing topic vs non-priority topics i.e. dedicated app1 which only consumes priority topic messages and processes them and concurrently app2 consumes non-priority messages and processes them.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have two listener containers, you could add `@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic` as a parameter to your method.

Then, when you receive a message from the priority topic, you could `stop()` the other listener container (using the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean), if it is running.

Configure `idleEventInterval` in the primary topic container and add an `@EventListner` method for `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`s (or an `ApplicationListener` bean).

Then, when you detect an idle primary container, you can restart the non-primary container.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So66366140Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So66366140Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66366140Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66366140-1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66366140-2").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Autowired
    KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @KafkaListener(id = "so66366140-1", topics = "so66366140-1")
    @KafkaListener(id = "so66366140-2", topics = "so66366140-2", autoStartup = "false")
    public void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        LOG.info(in);
        if (topic.equals("so66366140-1")
                && this.registry.getListenerContainer("so66366140-2").isRunning()) {
            LOG.info("Stopping non-pri container");
            this.registry.getListenerContainer("so66366140-2").stop();
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    void events(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        LOG.info(event.toString());
        if (event.getListenerId().startsWith("so66366140-1")
                && !this.registry.getListenerContainer("so66366140-2").isRunning()) {
            LOG.info("Starting non-pri container");
            this.registry.getListenerContainer("so66366140-2").start();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0,  10).forEach(i -> {
                template.send("so66366140-1", "foo");
                template.send("so66366140-2", "bar");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(6_000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            });
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.idle-event-interval=5s
```

You can also use pause/resume instead of stop/start.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Note that this will add latency equal to `idleEventInterval` to the first message present in non-priority topic. In case of applications that want to read everything as soon as possible but still maintain the priorities two separate consumers might be preferable.

Comment: Right; but he already has two consumers (via the 2 `@KafkaListener` annotations), so that's built in.